# get a Firestore document from a Workflow as json value only, without the metadata?

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore, google-workflows

How I can read the original JSON that was stored in Firestore document from my Google Workflow?

Because I only find a way to get a JSON with metadata value types instead.

This how I read the document:

```
- get_document:
    call: googleapis.firestore.v1.projects.databases.documents.get
    args:
      name: ${"projects/" + project_id + "/databases/(default)/documents/ + doc_path}
    result: r
```

Sample of the original JSON object:

```
{
    "a_text":"abcd", 
    ... 
}
```

Sample of the result:

```
{"createTime":"2022-11-24T00:16:46.641215Z",
 "fields": {
    "a_text":{"stringValue":"abcd"}, 
    ... 
},...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the result structure is to parse your custom result since the value of the API is already fixed unless changed by Firebase. Based on this documentation on the [Workflows Response documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/firestore/v1/projects.databases.documents/get):

> ### Response
>
> If successful, the response contains an instance of [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/firestore/v1/Overview#Document).

`Document` is a Firestore document which `Field` values are fixed unless otherwise changed by Firebase. You can check this link on [Document Fields](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/firestore/v1/Overview#document) for additional information.

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is too late. I created these subworkflows to solve this issue:

map_in_workflows: ${convert_doc_into_map(firestore_doc)}

firestore_fields: ${convert_map_into_doc(map_in_workflows)}

The following are the codes:

```
convert_map_into_doc:
  params: [map_value]
  steps:
    - create_firestore_map:
        assign:
          - firestore_map: {}
    - loop_over_keys:
        for:
          value: key
          in: ${keys(map_value)}
          steps:
            - assign_firestore_map:
                assign:
                  - firestore_map[key]: ${convert_value_to_field(map_value[key])}
    - return_result:
        return: ${firestore_map}

convert_value_to_field:
  params: [value]
  steps:
    - get_type:
        assign:
          - firestore_value: null
          - type: ${get_type(value)}
    - convert:
        switch:
          - condition: ${type == "integer"}
            steps:
              - add_integer:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        integerValue: ${value}
          - condition: ${type == "double"}
            steps:
              - add_double:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        doubleValue: ${value}
          - condition: ${type == "list"}
            steps:
              - create_array_values:
                  assign:
                    - arrayValues:
                        values: []
              - loop_over_array:
                  for:
                    value: array_value
                    in: ${value}
                    steps:
                      - create_value:
                          assign:
                            - converted_value: ${convert_value_to_field(array_value)}
                            - arrayValues:
                                values: ${list.concat(arrayValues.values, converted_value)}
              - add_array:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        arrayValue: ${arrayValues}
          - condition: ${type == "map"}
            steps:
              - add_map:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        mapValue:
                          fields: ${convert_map_into_doc(value)}
          - condition: ${type == "string"}
            steps:
              - add_string:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        stringValue: ${value}
          - condition: ${type == "boolean"}
            steps:
              - add_boolean:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        booleanValue: ${value}
          - condition: true
            steps:
              - add_null:
                  assign:
                    - firestore_value:
                        nullValue: NULL_VALUE
    - return_result:
        return: ${firestore_value}

convert_doc_into_map:
  params: [firestore_doc]
  steps:
    - create_workflow_map:
        assign:
          - workflow_map: {}
    - loop_over_keys:
        for:
          value: key
          in: ${keys(firestore_doc.fields)}
          steps:
            - assing_firestore_map:
                assign:
                  - workflow_map[key]: ${convert_field_to_value(map.get(firestore_doc.fields, key))}
    - return_result:
        return: ${workflow_map}

convert_field_to_value:
  params: [field]
  steps:
    - get_type:
        assign:
          - type: ${keys(field)[0]}
    - convert:
        switch:
          - condition: ${type != "arrayValue" and type != "mapValue"}
            steps:
              - return_value:
                  return: ${map.get(field, type)}
          - condition: ${type == "arrayValue"}
            steps:
              - create_array_values:
                  assign:
                    - values: []
              - loop_over_array:
                  for:
                    value: array_value
                    in: ${map.get(field, type).values}
                    steps:
                      - create_value:
                          assign:
                            - converted_value: ${convert_field_to_value(array_value)}
                            - values: ${list.concat(values, converted_value)}
              - return_array:
                  return: ${values}
          - condition: ${type == "mapValue"}
            steps:
              - return_map:
                  return: ${convert_doc_into_map(map.get(field, type))}
          - condition: true
            return: null
```